# Convert UTF-8 to Latin-1 in OSB 12C JCA FTP Adapter

Tags: utf-8, soa, latin1, jca, oracle-fusion-middleware

I have a scenerio to convert UTF-8 file format to latin-1/ISO 8859-1 in OSB 12C JCA FTP Adapter.Kindly help me to do the same.

Thanks in advance.
- Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

For inbound requests and outbound responses, the JCA adapter sends
messages to JCA proxy services with UTF-8 encoding.

But in the pipeline you change the encoding from UTF-8 to 'ISO 8859-1' which supports Latin-1.

1.) Open the pipeline

2.) Add the Transport Header component in the project pipeline.

3.) Click oh that Transport Header component and open properties.

4.) Select the Direction value from dropdown 'Outbound request' or 'Inbound Response'.

5.) In the header select the protocol type 'jca'.

6.) Add Action in header by clicking on + sign.

7.) In Action select 'SET' and in name select 'Content encoding' and in value put the encoding value as 'ISO 8859-1'.

8.) Save the project and test.

There is another way using X-query functions you can use that as well in the pipeline.